# Laravel 4 show posts that belongs to user after user logged in

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model

Im learning Laravel right know and im bumped in to a little problem.

I have created a login system that works just fine.
When a user is logged in he can create different posts.

Now the problem is when i login with for example Bob and create posts i can se all Bobs post in his profile page and that is OK!

But the problem i have is when i login with Alice i can see Bobs post and thats what i cant figure out how to solve.

I have some code that set the relations between user and post:

```
     //Post Model
    public function users(){
      return $this->hasMany('Posts');
}

    //User Model
   public functon posts(){

      return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

Now how can i show Alice posts only when i login to Alice account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple check on the profile page. Like comparing the id of the user who is logged in with the one whose profile is being accessed. If the Id matches that means the logged in user is the same as the profile user can see all of his posts while if the logged in user id is not equals to the id of user whose profile is being accessed posts will not be visible.

To get the posts of a a user you can do

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id','=', Auth::id())->get();
```

Don't know how your code is assembled so can't exactly write a code, but the above logic will work.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out as soon i get back from school! I have to test it in my PostController! :)